# Mobile grid app front page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a mobile app in html that will have an app style menu system, a 3x3 grid below a header in which evenly spaced buttons are in with icons on.

I've got the grid sort of working, but I can't seem to get any margin between the items (there needs to be clear defined areas). The bit i'm finding hard is that it has to scale properly on any device.

The following code produces this:

[image]

Which is partly there, heres what I want it to look like though; (excuse the poorly drawn lines, they should basically be spaces between allowing the background to show through).

[image]

Heres the code I have:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    counter-reset:image;
}
li {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    background-size:cover;
    width:33%;
    height:33%;
    top:33%;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px;
    position:absolute;
}
s
li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    top:0;
}
li:nth-child(n+7) {
    top:66%;
}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    left:33%;
}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    left:66%;
}

<div style="height:60%; margin: 20px">
 <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try to use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/c5kfehb1/) to make your point more clear?

Comment: Hey thanks for that...but not really. As if i could i'd have my problem sorted ;-). Basically I want my html/css to look like my second picture

Comment: That's why I copied it over there, to see what was wrong and play around with it. Would be hard working with abstract. Giving a real environment with the non-working code helps people who are trying to answer the question.

Comment: Okay, got it thanks. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Try [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/c5kfehb1/1/)